# How to set the autolayout constraints correctly for 4s?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

Hi i have screen and i set the constraints but the views are getting misplaced while seeing in the preview... Please suggest me how to set the constraints so that it adjusts all the screens.

[image: For 6s image]

But while previewing in 4s it displaces from its position

[image]

Comment: please show us the constraint you gave to those buttons

Comment: button's height and width is fixed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 - When height fixed
      1. button1- Give constraint lead to margin, top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button2), fix height. 
      2. button2- Give constraint top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button3), fix height. 
      3. button3- Give constraint top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button4), fix height.
      4. button4- Give constraint top(imageview) and trailing to margin, fix height.
      5. Select one button, after press command and select remaining button go to  pin option [right side down], select equal widths.

Case 2 - When height is not fixed
      1. button1- Give constraint lead to margin, top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button2), bottom (bottom layout guide). 
      2. button2- Give constraint top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button3), bottom (bottom layout guide). 
      3. button3- Give constraint top(imageview) and horizontal spacing(button4), bottom (bottom layout guide).
      4. button4- Give constraint top(imageview) and trailing to margin, bottom (bottom layout guide).
      5. Select one button, after press command and select remaining button go to  pin option [right side down], select equal widths and equal heights.

Note - In second case button height is bigger because we given bottom layout constraint so.
       In this you can use greater than or equal option for equal height constraint.

Answer (score 1):

For any view on giving auto layout, you have to provide the correct X,Y,width and its height. So starting from top and left you have to provide those constraints. First drag the UIView to storyboard and give the same width as of the Viewcontroller. Then give the constraints.
Here, the constraints for the view:
**Leading space to container margin**,
**Trailing to container margin**,
**Center horizontally**, and finally 
**Height** or **Center vertically** (as per your criteria)

Comment: The OP already knows this - they are asking why objects are changing alignment between different screen sizes...

Comment: If Leading and Trailing are given to a view as I suggested, then there will be no change in alignment. @norders

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not constraining the button relative to the margin. The margin changes from device to device. In the constraint editor click "First item" and make sure "Relative to margin" is *not* checked (or alternatively make sure *all* objects are relative to the margin).